# Bounding a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to show that

$$\left\vert\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+z-2}\right\vert\le \frac12$$

where $z$ are the points along the contour $\gamma(t)=e^{3it}$ where $t\in[0,\pi]$.

---

The numerator is easy:

$$\left\vert e^{iz}\right\vert = \left\vert\cos{z} + i\sin{z}\right\vert = \sqrt{\cos^2z+\sin^2z} = 1.$$

However the closest I can get for the denominator is

$$\left\vert z^2+z-2\right\vert \ge \vert z\vert^2 - \vert z\vert -2 = -2$$

but I need a $+2$. How would I find this?

Comment: Well, that's worse than the trivial bound $|z^2+z-2|\ge 0$, so you are definitely not on the right track. Actually, the bound you are trying to prove for the denominator is false: set $t=0$.

Comment: Also note that Euler's formula was used incorrectly in the numerator.  In general, $|e^{iz}| = e^{-\operatorname{Im}(z)}.$

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro So.. How do I find it then.. You're no help just telling me I'm wrong.

Comment: @OpenSeason Same goes for you..

Comment: Take it or leave it, I won't be assisting you any further.

Answer (score 0):

That is the same as proving
$$ |z+2|\cdot |z-1| \geq 2\cdot|e^{iz}|=2\cdot e^{-\text{Im}(z)},\qquad z=e^{3it},t\in[0,\pi] $$
or:
$$ \forall t\in[0,\pi],\qquad\left\|e^{3it}+2\right\|^2\cdot \left\|e^{3it}-1\right\|^2 \geq 4\cdot e^{-\sin(3t)} $$
or:
$$ \forall u\in[0,3\pi],\qquad (5+4\cos(u))(1-\cos(u))\geq 2e^{-\sin(u)} $$
but that is not true in a right neighbourhood of the origin, or at $u=2\pi$.